# What's the best climbing website?

Tags: climbing, rock-climbing, bouldering

I've not found a "must read," general information (news, trends, photos, product reviews, etc.) rock climbing website.

Climbing.com, for example, is riddled with missing images and dead links, which I find infuriating, although it does seem to have some interesting content if you have the patience to wade through the morass. But, more generally, this and other climbing magazine sites seem focused on ads and promoting print subscriptions; they provide little tangible digital content. And a significant portion of the content they do provide is about ice climbing/alpinist info which are, in my opinion, very different from rock climbing.

On the other hand, rockclimbing.com and mountainproject.com have useful route databases. Wikipedia has a great list of climbing terms. Climbfind.com is a good resource for finding a local climbing partner. But their content is mostly limited to these specific topics.

Is there a general information climbing website/blog that is considered "must read" among serious rock climbers?

Comment: This question asks for more of a list rather than a definitive answer, which isn't usually the sort of questions we're after - no denying that it has the potential to be useful, but perhaps better to rephrase the question to something a bit more specific?

Comment: @berry120 Point taken. I think I've improved the question.

Comment: @amacy -- All the issues and problems you describe about missing images, dead links, etc are a part of what SE addresses.  

Even if we did have a "best climbing site" (that was not us), the answer would quite likely become out of date relatively quickly, the web being what it is.

I'm closing the question.  If you feel strongly and want it reopened, please post in meta to discuss.  http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Climbfind.com](http://climbfind.com) is a great place to find a local partner.